# Acurrate gps lat long

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, location

Is there any way to acurrate or put a range within `latitude` or `longitude`?

My app will be looking for user current `lat` & `long` with a `BroadcastRecevier` and I want to put a range or something.

I'm using [`Place picker`](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/placepicker) and I'm getting a `lat/long` i.e : (`lat/lng: (41.48256,2.317142)`) value with `place.getLatLong()` so I want the **acurrate for those values**.

Comment: U mean u want the accuracy of the location ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
location.getAccuracy()
```

to get the accuracy in meters.

From the docs

> Get the estimated accuracy of this location, in meters.
>
> We define accuracy as the radius of 68% confidence. In other words, if
>   you draw a circle centered at this location's latitude and longitude,
>   and with a radius equal to the accuracy, then there is a 68%
>   probability that the true location is inside the circle.
>
> In statistical terms, it is assumed that location errors are random
>   with a normal distribution, so the 68% confidence circle represents
>   one standard deviation. Note that in practice, location errors do not
>   always follow such a simple distribution.
>
> This accuracy estimation is only concerned with horizontal accuracy,
>   and does not indicate the accuracy of bearing, velocity or altitude if
>   those are included in this Location.
>
> If this location does not have an accuracy, then 0.0 is returned. All
>   locations generated by the LocationManager include an accuracy.

**UPDATE**

What you are trying to do is called geofencing. Please have a look at [this](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html).

Comment: Well the thing is that I have a `place_picker` so I get a lat and long, with this I want to get accuracy of it. Can I do it with `getAccuracy()`?

Comment: SO you are not getting a location object, just lat and long??

Comment: I'm getting something like `lat/lng: (41.48256,2.317142)` (that's a log)

Comment: Ohk, well I haven't worked on placepicker, so I can't say how you can get accuracy with just the lat and long values. But if you somehow manage to get the location object then it is a piece of cake.

Comment: I'll need to use a `Location object` since I've to get the lat long value of user so I'll need to compare it with the lat / long value from the placepicker, I can do it with your code?

Comment: You want to get the accuracy of user's location, right?

Comment: Oh maybe I failed at the time to formulate the question... the thing is : 1.- get only lat long 2.- on a broadcastreceiver I'll get the lat long of the user 3.- I want to compare the lat long of placepicker and the current lat long of the user and I don't want to the user **MUST** be at the same lat long I just want to give to him a range or something

Comment: The location that you get in the broadcast receiver is the user's location. The user might not be at the same place cause the lat long that are returned are not exact. The accuracy of the user you can get by location.getAccuracy(). How do you get the lat longs of the user in the broadcast receiver ?, there must be some way you are doing it. If the lat longs, are fetched from a location object, like location.getLatitutde and location.getLongitude, then you can also send user's accuracy with location.getAccuracy !!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91304/discussion-between-skizo-and-varunkr).